# rx java observable chaining on only matched observables

Tags: java, groovy, rx-java

I have a list that I'm iterating over and I want to print out only matching items in the list (I know this is trivial but it's just a learning exercise for rx java). I'm also using the groovy extensions.

```
    def scheduler = Schedulers.immediate()
    Observable.from(["a","b","c"]).takeFirst({
        return it == "b"
    }).subscribeOn(scheduler).subscribe({println it})
```

This works and only prints out `b` as expected. What I'm wondering if can I move the `println it` to before `subscribeOn` call so it's something like

```
    def scheduler = Schedulers.immediate()
    Observable.from(["a","b","c"]).takeFirst({
        return it == "b"
    }).SOMEOPERATIONHERE({println it}).subscribeOn(scheduler)
```

I could use `map` or `flatmap`, but that seems a wrong because I'm not actually mapping one observable to another. I just want to perform some `void` operation on the observable at the end of the chain, but I like the syntax of having all of the operations together before the `subscribeOn` call.

Comment: So you are looking for `doOnNext`?

Comment: Yep, thanks. Please add this as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `doOnNext`to register an action to take whenever an Observable emits an item. There are also other `doOnXXX` operators in RxJava for registering actions to monitor progress of an Observable, such as `doOnCompleted`, `doOnError`.